# PlayWright Wait for second response

Tags: .net, playwright-dotnet

after clicking the delete button on my page, that triggers the DELETE on server side, I do a GET if the response was successfull. How to I get the second response, which is GET-call from server, without any trigger event in PlayWright?

```
 var fetchUrl ="an url";

 await Page.RunAndWaitForResponseAsync(async () =>
        {
            await deleteButton.ClickAsync();
        }, response => response.Status == 200);

  //this code is not working the response do not wait here
  var secondResponse = await Page.WaitForResponseAsync(r => 
        r.Url.Contains(fetchUrl));
```